# javascript tokenizer

Tags: javascript

I have a question about splitting string in javascript. I'm getting a string from somewhere else and I want to get only a part of it. I can't use substr because its length can be altered. I also looked at split method, but it is not enough also. For example, one of my strings looks like this:

```
<img src="http://image.weather.com/web/common/wxicons/31/30.gif?12122006" alt="" />Partly Cloudy, and 84 &deg; F. For more details?
```

I only want to get img tag and the number 84. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: What are the constants in your string, e.g., is the `&deg;` present in all strings?

Comment: only img source, "Partly Cloudy" and the number can alter. Rest is same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where one should use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

You can do something like:

```
var inputStr = '<img src="http://image.weather.com/web/common/wxicons/31/30.gif?12122006" alt="" />Partly Cloudy, and 84 &deg; F. For more details?';
var regex = /<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>.*?([0-9]+\s*&deg;\s*[CF])/;
var results = regex.exec(inputStr);

results[1]; // => "http://image.weather.com/web/common/wxicons/31/30.gif?12122006"
results[2]; // => "84 &deg; F"
```

See a working example using this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/epkcn/

Comment: it doesn't return anything. I followed what u wrote

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle showing a live example using code similar to the above.  I've added it to the answer and will copy it here for your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/epkcn/

Comment: i think I have another mistake because your code is working. Anyway thank you, I will fix my error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var root = document.createElement("div");
root.innerHTML = '<img src="http://image.weather.com/web/common/wxicons/31/30.gif?12122006" alt="" />Partly Cloudy, and 84 &deg; F. For more details?';

var src = root.firstChild.src; //the src
var number = +root.firstChild.nextSibling.nodeValue.match( /\d+/ )[0]; //84
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to specify exactly what you want to look for in a string.